# Generate a XML and update it in a table in sql server without using cursor

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm using a cursor to generate a XML file for each row. I'm selecting a list of  IDs from the xml_temp_table. Then I have to update these XML files in another table (LOCATION_TABLE_XML). I've realized this cursor is not efficient if I have more than 20K rows to update. Thanks, I really appreciate it.

```
     DECLARE @xml_var XML;
     DECLARE @ID INT;
     DECLARE XML_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
     SELECT id
     FROM   xml_temp_table
     WHERE  id IS NOT NULL;

    OPEN XML_CURSOR;
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM  XML_CURSOR
    INTO  @ID;

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
 SET @xml_var =
(
     SELECT
            (
                   SELECT 'Type'    AS ID,
                          'Initial' AS VALUE,
                          ''        AS TAG,
                          'true'    AS VISIBLE,
                          Getdate() AS HISTORY,
                          ''        AS DESCRIPTION,
                          ''        AS COMMENT
                   FROM   XML_TABLE d
                   WHERE  D.XML_ID = @ID FOR XML PATH('field'),
                          TYPE ) AS '[*]',
            (
                   SELECT 'OwnerName'   AS ID,
                          'Testing_XML' AS VALUE,
                          ''            AS TAG,
                          'true'        AS VISIBLE,
                          Getdate()     AS HISTORY,
                          ''            AS DESCRIPTION,
                          ''            AS COMMENT
                   FROM   XML_TABLE d
                   WHERE  D.XML_ID = @ID FOR XML PATH('field'),
                          TYPE ) AS '[*]'
     FROM   XML_TABLE p
     WHERE  P.XML_ID = @ID FOR XML PATH('Material'),
            ROOT('FormValue') );
 UPDATE S
 SET    S.XML_COL = @xml_var,
 FROM   LOCATION_TABLE_XML S
 WHERE  S.ID = @ID;

 FETCH NEXT
  FROM  XML_CURSOR
  INTO  @ID;

  END;
```

The Required output

```
<FormValue>
 <Material>
  <field>
  <id>Type</id>
  <value>Initial</value>
  <tag />
  <visible>true</visible>
<history>2016-11-08</history>
<description />
<comment />
</field>
<field>
  <id>OwnerName</id>
  <value>Testing_XML</value>
  <tag />
  <visible>true</visible>
  <history>2016-11-08</history>
<description />
<comment />
</field>
</Material>
</FormValue>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing for sure: **You do not need a `CURSOR` here...**

Cursors are bad and evil... They are invented by the data devil to lead us poor developers away from the light of *set-based* thinking. It's pulling you down into the dark acres of *procedural pain*... (Well, there are some cases, where a `CURSOR` is the right choice, but these are rare...)

I've stolen the test scenario from John Cappeletti (thx John! *+d* you...) and think this can be simplified:

No need for the `CROSS APPLY`... As the XML is a scalar value it can be used directly. And there's no need to join the `CTE` back to `@YourTable` as the `CTE` is updateable itself:

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Active bit,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50),XMLData xml)
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,1,'John','Smith','john.smith@email.com',null),
(2,0,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@email.com',null)

;with cte as 
(
    Select A.ID
          ,A.XMLData
          ,( 
                    -- This would be your XML generation
                    -- Notice the reference to A.ID
                    Select XMLData = (Select * From @YourTable Where ID=A.ID For XML Path('root')) 
           ) AS NewXML
     From  @YourTable A
) 
Update cte Set XMLData = NewXML;

Select * from @YourTable
```

But this can be put even simpler: I need to create the table physically now, since we'd need a table's alias otherwise...

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable(ID int,Active bit,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50),XMLData xml);
Insert into YourTable values
(1,1,'John','Smith','john.smith@email.com',null),
(2,0,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@email.com',null);

UPDATE YourTable SET XMLData= ( 
                                -- This would be your XML generation
                                Select x.* From YourTable AS x Where x.ID=YourTable.ID For XML Path('root')
                               )

Select * from YourTable
GO

DROP TABLE YourTable;
```

**Attention 1**: I understand your sentence *I'm selecting a list of IDs from the xml_temp_table* that you need to filter this process to a list of IDs. If so, just add

```
WHERE YourTable.ID IN(SELECT filter.ID FROM SomeWhere AS filter)
```

**Attention 2**: The sentence *Then I have to update these XML files in another table* is not clear to me... If you want to **create** these rows in the other table, just use

```
INSERT INTO OtherTable(col1,col2,...) SELECT col1,col2, ... FROM ...
```

If the other table has got corresponding rows with the IDs given, you can easily change the statements to correspond to this. If you need help, just come back...

Comment: Yup, over-thinking it again.  I've removed my shame unless you think it helps with your narrative ... what not to do.